# How does Amazon Athena manage rename of columns?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, pyarrow, aws-glue-data-catalog

everyone!

I'm working on a solution that intends to use Amazon Athena to run SQL queries from Parquet files on S3.
Those filed will be generated from a PostgreSQL database (RDS). I'll run a query and export data to S3 using Python's Pyarrow.

My question is: since Athena is schema-on-read, add or delete of columns on database will not be a problem...but what will happen when I get a column renamed on database?

Day 1: COLUMNS['col_a', 'col_b', 'col_c']

Day 2: COLUMNS['col_a', 'col_beta', 'col_c']

On Athena,

```
SELECT col_beta FROM table;
```

will return only data from Day 2, right?
Is there a way that Athena knows about these schema evolution or I would have to run a script to iterate through all my files on S3, rename columns and update table schema on Athena from 'col_a' to 'col_beta'?

Would AWS Glue Data Catalog help in any way to solve this?

I'll love to discuss more about this!

Comment: Try it and let us know what you find! I suspect that parquet files are a little bit clever and know the column names (rather than relying on the columns being in a particular order), so they will use whatever column has that name.

Comment: You are renaming the columns on your CSV/TSV file right?

Comment: @NishantSingh it will be a Parquet file, but yes.
At a given day, Parquet file generated would have a different column compared to previous days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading more about handling schema updates with Athena [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/handling-schema-updates-chapter.html). Generally Athena supports multiple ways of reading Parquet files (as well as other columnar data formats such as ORC). By default, using Parquet, columns will be read by name, but you can change that to reading by index as well. Each way has its own advantages / disadvantages dealing with schema changes. Based on your example, you might want to consider reading by index if you are sure new columns are only appended to the end.

A Glue crawler can help you to keep your schema updated (and versioned), but it doesn't necessarily help you to resolve schema changes (logically). And it comes at an additional cost, of course.

Another approach could be to use a schema that is a superset of all schemas over time (using columns by name) and define a view on top of it to resolve changes "manually".

Comment: Hi, Moritz!
I've already read about it. Read by index has a drawback in case my dataset had deleted columns.
I'm not seeing a straightforward solution to handle rename of columns that doesn't demand specific action on files...I would have to coalesce renamed columns on Athena schema, or iterate through files and replicate those changes, which can become a problem along time

Answer (score 0):

You can set a granularity based on 'On Demand' or 'Time Based' for the AWS Glue crawler, so every time your data on the S3 updates a new schema will be generated (you can edit the schema on the data types for the attributes). This way your columns will stay updated and you can query on the new field.

Comment: Hi, @Vibek
That way, my schema on AWS Glue would have both 'col_b' and 'col_beta'?

Answer (score 0):

Since AWS Athena reads data in CSV and TSV in the "order of the columns" in the schema and returns them in the same order. It does not use column names for mapping data to a column, which is why you can rename columns in CSV or TSV without breaking Athena queries.